# Load view from the helper, CI

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

So, I tried all these methods

```
$CI = CI_Controller::get_instance();

#or $CI =& get_instance();

$CI->load->view('pages/home');
```

but I don't get anything. if I make a mistake in a

`Unable to load the requested file: pages/homes.php`, but if file is correct, I still get nothing

also, I can use `$CI->load->helper(some helper)` and use its function and `echo` their results.

Sorry if my question is stupid, but I searched alot and didn't find a problem as I have.

Comment: Bad way. Just use `$this->load->view()`

Comment: What is the workflow? Why would you load view from helper?

Comment: @Spartan i can't use $this in helper, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow following steps:

- Controller

  ```
  class Stackoverflow extends CI_Controller{

      function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();

          $this->load->helper('global_helper'); // load helper
      }

      function index(){
          call_view(); //calling of helper function
      }
  }
  ```
- Helper (global_helper.php)

  ```
  function call_view(){
      $CI = get_instance(); //creating instance of CI
      $CI->load->view('view'); //loading of view.php
  }
  ```
- View (view.php)

  ```
  <html>
      <head>
          <title>View from Helper</title>
      </head>
      <body>
          <p>This is text from helper</p>
      </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Thx a lot! I made nearly the same, but the problem was in my controller.